# Remove Space Code %20 From String || Decode URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In my email, I have a link that uses ampscript and one of the values has a space, so the url ends up looking like this: https://mysite.com/group=Group%202

How do I convert this to https://mysite.com/group=Group2 ? Essentially I want to remove the space code "%20"

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to decode your your url then you can do it as below.

```ampscript
<script runat='server' language='javascript'>
 Platform.Load('Core','1.1');
    var  URL = "https://mysite.com/group=Group%202"
    var decodedURL = decodeURI(URL)
    Write(decodedURL);
 </script>
```

> Output = `https://mysite.com/group=Group 2`

---

If you just want to remove the space from your URLs, you can use the below approach.

```ampscript
%%[
    set @URL = "https://mysite.com/group=Group%202"
    SET @URL = Replace(@URL,'%20','')
]%%
URL with space removed = %%=URLEncode(@URL)=%%
```

> Output = `https://mysite.com/group=Group2`